# Create a file with echo in DOS without inserting a carriage return

Tags: dos

I want to create a new file on my CIFS mount in DOS.  If I do..

```
echo hello > foo.txt
```

There is going to be a CR at the end of hello.  How can I create a file at the DOS cmd using echo and not have a CR automatically appended.  It is causing problems with samba and my CIFS mount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo.|set /P ="hello" > foo.txt
```

Comment: @CharlesB That link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: `set /p "noEOL=hello" <nul >foo.txt`

`set /p` outputs what comes after the equal sign to prompt the user for input (see `help set`). If you redirect the user input from `nul` it is happy to continue, redirecting its output to your foo.txt. The name of the variable to assign to is arbitrary (here `noEOL`).