# AWK equivalent in batch scripting

Tags: awk, find, batch-file

I want an batch scripting equivalent to this AWK script:

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

A file has this content:

```
XXX YYY : 8
Rrr rrr : 7
ddd rrr : 9
```

I want to get a batch script to print

```
8, 7, 9
```

Is there any way by which each value can be assigned to a loop and redirected to if condition?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this question should cover it?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536018/how-to-get-match-regex-pattern-using-awk-from-file

Answer (score 8):

I can't tell if your asking for a Windows Batch script or an awk script, so here's both:

test.txt:

```
XXX YYY : 8
Rrr rrr : 7
ddd rrr : 9
```

**AWK**:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {printf ", "}{printf $4}END{printf "\n"}' test.txt
```

Output:

```
8, 7, 9
```

---

**Windows Batch script**:

```
@echo off
SET _c=
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%G IN (test.txt) DO (
    IF DEFINED _c <nul set /p z=", "
    <nul set /p z=%%G
    SET _c=1
)
```

Output:

```
8, 7, 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand why you are using `<nul set /p` instead of `set` alone? Can you elaborate?

Comment: `<nul set /p var="text"` is just a hack for printing "text" to the screen without carriage return and linefeed characters.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something (although I'll forget it tomorrow :). For future reference and those that are wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623599/create-a-file-with-echo-in-dos-without-inserting-a-carriage-return

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: '{x=x","$2;}END{print substr(x,2,length(x)-1)}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
XXX YYY : 8
Rrr rrr : 7
ddd rrr : 9
> awk -F: '{x=x","$2;}END{print substr(x,2,length(x)-1)}' temp
 8, 7, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
 awk '{ if(NR<3) printf "%s, ", $4 }END{ print $4 }' file
```

Result:

```
echo -e "XXX YYY : 8\nRrr rrr : 7\nddd rrr : 9" | awk '{ if(NR<3) printf "%s, ", $4 }END{ print $4 }'
8, 7, 9
```

Comment: Why the if-condition? You can just `print ""` in `END` for the empty line. It will also be more general.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk '{print $3}'` will print a list of `:` from your sample file, not the numbers. You should have used `$4`. Or, you are showing us the wrong file format here.

The exact Windows equivalent of that Awk script is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%a IN (file.txt) DO ECHO %%a
```

But then the required output you showed `8, 7, 9` isn't what your Awk script prints either.
The simplest batch command producing output close to that is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%a IN (file.txt) DO <nul SET /p="%%a, "
```

If you really can't stand the extra comma in the end, it gets more complicated:

```
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%a IN (file.txt) DO <nul CALL SET /p=%%,%% %%a& SET ,=,
```

**AWK on Windows**

By the way, Awk is available for Windows. Quoting is different, so your script would be:

```
awk "{printf $4 \", \"}" file.txt
```

Or to get rid of that extra comma, it becomes slightly more messy:

```
awk "{printf (NR>1?\", \":\"\") $4}" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

### OUTPUT TO THE TERMINAL DIRECTLY

**If you already have awk.exe try step (3) first before attempting (1:3)**

**AWK** was superseded by **GAWK** which is also backwards compatible (Check **(3)** ).

1. **Get the Right GAWK**

   So I used Gawk v3.6.1 running the setup [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/gawk/3.1.6-1/gawk-3.1.6-1-setup.exe/download). Run the **gawk-3.1.6-1-setup.exe**.

   During install note the path to the directory you extract/install to, **check mark both Binaries & Documentation** & the rest is your preference.
2. **Extract GAWK**

   Once installed, extract ***gawk.exe*** from the install directory by navigating to the path you noted in install & going to the **bin directory**. 
   Copy **gawk.exe** then navigate to the directory of the batch file (*.bat) you wish to give gawk functionality & paste it (since its a portable *.exe & the purpose of my batch needs to be self contained).
3. **Use the Right Commands**

   These commands print directly to the terminal nicely formatted the keyword I was missing took an entire day to find scouring the internet, then reading a text file almost 2000 lines long & finding **BEGIN** before the braces. 
   It didn't occur to me until reading the **gawk.1.txt** in ***\man\cat1**

   ```
   gawk "BEGIN { print \"Hello world\"}"

   REM If you have printf from GNUwin32
   gawk "BEGIN { printf \"Hello world\"}"
   ```

Comment: Correction: 'printf' I obtained from CoreUtils for Windows